# Exception :OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException:

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, protractor-net

### Below exception thrown when i ran a test with following configuration Protractor.net with c# Nunit

```
 1. "NUnit" version="3.11.0"
 2. "NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.12.0"
 3. "Protractor" version="0.12.0"
 4. "Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.141.0"
 5. "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" version="2.36.0"
 6. Chromebrowser Version :  65.0.3325.162
```

angular.version
{full: "1.6.9", major: 1, minor: 6, dot: 9, codeName: "fiery-basilisk"}

### Below sample code that i have used for testing and it fails at NgBy.Repeater

```
private IWebDriver driver;
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
public void uitest()
{
try {
      ngDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("");           
      ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id("userNameInput")).SendKeys("");            
      ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id("passwordInput")).SendKeys("");
      ngDriver.FindElement(By.Id("submitButton")).Click();
      string text=ngDriver.FindElements(NgBy.Repeater(""))[0].Text;
      Assert.AreEqual("Dashboard", text);
}catch(Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine("Exception :"+e.ToString());
Assert.True(false);
}
driver.Quit();
}
```

Exception :

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:61649/session/f5f68e3d39a9e0e5adee0c5d76acd9d1/execute_async timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteAsyncScript(String script, Object[] args)
   at Protractor.NgWebDriver.WaitForAngular() in c:\Users\Bruno\Projets\GitHub\bbaia\protractor-net\src\Protractor\NgWebDriver.cs:line 359
   at Protractor.NgWebDriver.FindElements(By by) in c:\Users\Bruno\Projets\GitHub\bbaia\protractor-net\src\Protractor\NgWebDriver.cs:line 299
```

Comment: As you can see "http://localhost:61649/session/f5f68e3d39a9e0e5adee0c5d76acd9d1/execute_async timed out after 60 seconds"  so increase the timeout 60 to 180 and see if it works.

Comment: @BhaveshSoni - Still same issue  exist after increasing to 180 seconds

Comment: If you open URL manually, Does it work fine? how much time does it take to load the page completely?

Comment: 30 seconds... the issue is when it try to find element using ngrepeat it fails not in other line of code

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `IgnoreSynchronization` to `true` and call `WaitForAngular()` method for angular page

```
ngDriver.IgnoreSynchronization = true;
ngDriver.WaitForAngular();
```

Add this in `SetUp()` method or try using at line where  you are facing issue